# Azure ML Service dump logs

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

With the AzureML service, how can I dump the correct Loss curve or Accuracy curve for different epochs for keras deep learning on multiple nodes with Horovod?

The Loss vs epochs plt from Keras deep learning using Horovod and AzureML appears to have issues.

Training CNN with Keras/Horovod (2 GPUs) and AMLS SDK generates weird graphs
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you might be training 2 models and the averaging of the gradients from the different nodes is note happening. Can you share more of your training script -- are you wrapping your optimizer in a `DistributedOptimizer` like so:

```py
# Horovod: adjust learning rate based on number of GPUs.
opt = keras.optimizers.Adadelta(1.0 * hvd.size())

# Horovod: add Horovod Distributed Optimizer.
opt = hvd.DistributedOptimizer(opt)
```

In addition, you really only want one machine to log, so usually only attach an AzureML logger for rank 0, like so:

```py
class LogToAzureMLCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
  def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
    Run.get_context().log('acc',logs['acc'])

  def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
    Run.get_context().log('epoch_acc',logs['acc'])

callbacks = [
    # Horovod: broadcast initial variable states from rank 0 to all other processes.
    # This is necessary to ensure consistent initialization of all workers when
    # training is started with random weights or restored from a checkpoint.
    hvd.callbacks.BroadcastGlobalVariablesCallback(0)
]

# Horovod: save checkpoints only on worker 0 and only log to AzureML from worker 0.
if hvd.rank() == 0:
    callbacks.append(keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('./checkpoint-{epoch}.h5'))
    callbacks.append(LogToAzureMLCallback())

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          callbacks=callbacks,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you logging these metrics? From the graph it looks like there's two sets of datapoints interleaved.